# Getting data from a Public Google Sheets in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to access a public spreadsheet (shared between about 200 people);

The link is as follows: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1SOME_ID/pubhtml

I tried using:

```py
import gspread

sa = gspread.service_account(filename='kegg-380416-535391437509.json')

spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-SOME_ID/pubhtml'
sa.open_by_url(spreadsheet_url)
```

In return I get `{'code': 404, 'message': 'Requested entity was not found.', 'status': 'NOT_FOUND'}`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I also get a 404 error when opening the spreadsheet in the browser

Comment: Of course this won't work, that's an invalid link. In fact you can notice `SOME_ID` in the same link. You need to ask for the right link